# Seagate 4TB drive not seen by Windows 7 installer on Thinkcentre M57

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm trying to install a 4TB Seagate ST4000DM000 in a Thinkcentre M57p box I'm trying to use as a media center, but the Windows 7 (64 bit) installer detects no drives when selecting a target volume; there's an option to load a driver, but I have no idea which one to use.

Comment: Maybe you need to activate SATA or use the motherboard's SATA drivers.

Comment: Check on your motherboard manufacturer's website and see if they have a driver or update for this.  My motherboard required a BIOS update and a special driver to address 3TB and larger drives.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the Intel ICH9 south gate and it is limited on 2Tb in RAID mode and IDE. If you want to install the 4Tb HDD than use AHCI mode. There are a lot of bad experience with Intel original drivers, while Microsoft AHCI drivers are working flawlessly

To sum up... use SATA in AHCI mode and use Microsoft AHCI drivers and let me know is it working this way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Windows on a drive larger than 2 TB.  You CAN use drives larger, but Windows cannot be installed ***UNLESS*** the machine uses UEFI instead of BIOS.  Windows can only boot from disks that large when they are set to GPT instead of classic MBR.  And BIOS cannot boot GPT disks.  At best, you'll be able to use the drive and lose 2TB worth of space.

Instead, use the 4TB drive as a second drive to store your recordings and install Windows to another disk smaller than 2TB (my own media center has 8 hard drives between 1 and 3 TB each).